# Sharing a link on facebook with a full sized image instead of a thumbnail

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-share

I am working with a project where the user will be able to share a product from my app to facebook. In this action, the user will edit the following data:

- The quote/description of the product.
- Set a place for the post.
- Share an image from my app gallery.

When the user shares my product it generates a standard hashtag, and the user may select a place for check in.

Here is the image of the desired action.

[Sharing product on Facebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAlab.png)

So i followed several tutorials on youtube and the documentation from facebook so i managed to use SharePhoto and Share Link with success. In my share button im using share link and setting the following properties :

```
String url_link_loja = "www.centauro.com.br";
            ShareHashtag.Builder hashtag = new ShareHashtag.Builder();
            hashtag.setHashtag("#Olympikus");
            String url_imagem = "https://static.olympikus.com.br/produtos/tenis-olympikus-thin-2-feminino/91/D22-0304-791/D22-0304-791_zoom1.jpg?resize=1200:*";


ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                    .setContentUrl(Uri.parse(url_imagem_test))
                    .setQuote(url_link_loja)
                    .setImageUrl(Uri.parse(url_imagem))
                    .setShareHashtag(hashtag.build())
                    .setPlaceId("Avenida Paulista")
                    .build();



            shareDialog.show(linkContent);
```

Then, when i share with my app i get just a thumbnail of the image instead of a full sized image.

[Share Dialog on Nexus xl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgTm3.png)

When i use Share Photo instead, i get the full image on the dialog window just the way i want, however it seems its not possible to add hashtag and quote on this object. I tried to fix this using open graph, so i used the book example from the documentation and tried do add image, but when i do, i get a callback error message that dos not specifies the problem( i already checked, its not the commom namespace error).

So, i need some advice on the matter, any insight will be helpful.